# consider a base-16 adder. explain how to modify the adder so that it can perform a base-10 addition

Tags: boolean-algebra

consider a base-16 adder. explain how to modify the adder so  that it can perform a base-10 addition

I found this when I searched in Google but  not understand

[image]

please guide me to understand this question so  that I can solve it

Answer (score 1):

Lets consider the case of a single digit addition:
you have two base-$16$ numbers $x$ and $y$  ($4$ bits each) and want to produce $z = x+y$. 
Note that for $z$ we will allow $8$ bits (two base-$16$ digits) as we may have a carryover by the addition and we will need to store it somewhere.

Lets see how the base-$16$ adder works, through an example:
$$
\begin{array}{rlcccl}
 &x&      & 0011 &  (3)_{16}\\
+&y&      & 0100 &  (4)_{16}\\
=&z& 0000 & 0111 &  (7)_{16} & [0, 7]_{\text{BCD}}
\end{array}
$$
In this case, we added $3$ and $4$ and produced number $7$. There was no carryover and $z$ effectively can be stored in a single base-$16$ digit.
The important thing to realize is that the base-$16$ representation of $z$ is also good to go as a BCD representation: the left most digit is $0000$ ($=(0)_{10}$)and the right most is $0111 = (7)_{10}$.
So no modification is needed: all that changes is *how  you read the output*.

The problem is that each base-$16$ digit can store a value up to $15$ which is larger than $9$, which in turn is the largest value for a digit in the BCD representation. Consider the following example:
$$
\begin{array}{rlccc}
 &x&      & 0111 &  (7)_{16}\\
+&y&      & 0111 &  (7)_{16}\\
=&z& 0000 & 1110 &  (14)_{16}
\end{array}
$$
Now, the right-most base-$16$ digit of $z$ is $(14)_{16}$.
Instead, the BCD representation should be:
$$
\begin{array}{rlccc}
& 0001 & 0100 & & [1, 4]_{\text{BCD}}.
\end{array}
$$
So from the digit holding the value $(14)_{16}$, we would have to go to a digit holding the value $(4)_{16}$ and get a carryover to put in the left most digit.
This can be done by adding $(6)_{16}$ to $z$:
$$
\begin{array}{rlcccl}
 &z& 0000 & 1110 &  (14)_{16}\\
+&6&      & 0110 &  (6)_{16}\\
=&z^{'}& 0001 & 0100 &  (20)_{16} & [1, 4]_{\text{BCD}}
\end{array}
$$

The general rule is the following:
*If the sum produced by the base-$16$ adder is greater than $9$ then you have to add $6$ to get the correct digit and propagate the carryover.*

I will conclude with one more example to clarify something:
$$
\begin{array}{rlccc}
 &x&      & 1000&  (8)_{16}\\
+&y&      & 1000 &  (8)_{16}\\
=&z& 0001 & 0000 &  (16)_{16}
\end{array}
$$
The left-most digit of $z$ is $0000 = (0)_{16}$ which is smaller than $9$. But the **sum** is equal to $16$ (we have a carryover). 
So the **sum** is **greater** than $9$. So we have to add $6$ to get the right BCD representation. Indeed:
$$
\begin{array}{rlcccl}
 &z& 0001 & 0000 &  (16)_{16}\\
+&6&      & 0110 &  (6)_{16}\\
=&z^{'}& 0001 & 0110 &  (22)_{16} & [1, 6]_{\text{BCD}}.
\end{array}
$$
Hope this helps.